# msdtc and isolation level

Tags: sql-server, transactions, isolation-level, read-committed-snapshot

I need some clarification how MS-DTC will behave in scenario given below

1) I  have more than one connection in within a transactionscope (Isolation level - ReadCommited),which will bring MS- DTC into action now :

a) Will MS-DTC automatically change isolation level to SERIALIZABLE.

b) (Imp) If above answer is yes and I have implemented Row versioning based isolation level i.e. in addition to TransactionScope, i have also enabled the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT database option "ON", will it remain in effect means will it support "SERIALIZABLE" isolation level.

```
void OuterMethod() {
    TransactionOptions tso = new TransactionOptions();
    tso.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
    using (TransactionScope tx = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, tso)) {
        InnerMethod("select * from testtable");
        InnerMethod("update testtable set col1 = N'new value'");
        tx.Complete();
    }
}

static void InnerMethod(string sqlText) {
    using (SqlConnection conn = SqlConnection(connStr)) {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serializable is the default isolation level but [MS DTC will respect the Isolation Level you specify in your TransactionOptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/florinlazar/archive/2003/12/10/42686.aspx).

**UPDATE**

1) Yes, MS DTC Will be involved.

1a) No (see above).

1b) The previous answer is not yes, but it is my understanding that READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT is only in effect if the isolation level is read committed.  Other isolation levels will enforce their own locking model. ["When the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT option is set to ON, read operations *under the read committed isolation level* are based on row versions and are executed in a nonlocking mode."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345124%28SQL.90%29.aspx)